# On win7 with Python 3.2.1, what's special character following the read string from command line?

Tags: windows-7, input, python-3.x

I have a script in a file:

```
#../Python32/Test.py
y = input("Please input:")
print("'" + y + "'")
```

from command line, I run the script, and the result is different between XP and Win7:

On XP:

```
> Python Text.py
Please input:h
'h'
```

On Win7, the result is:

```
> Python Text.py
Please input:h
'h
```

On Win7, the second single quote is missed in the result.

But if the script is like following:

```
#../Python32/Test2.py
y = input("Please input:")
print("'" + y.rstrip() + "'")
```

The results are the same on both win7 and XP.

```
> Python Text.py
Please input:h
'h'
```

Comparing the results, there should be special character following the read string from command line on win7. I searched it on the internet and tried all the ways which I know, but cannot get the answer.

What's the special character followed the read string via command line on win7?  Or is there a way that I can print the special character in my script?

Thanks advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You have a carriage return in the string, from the CRLF line ending on Windows. This moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, overwriting the first quote. `input()` is supposed to remove that. I thought that bug was [fixed in 3.2.1](http://bugs.python.org/issue11272). Are you sure you're not using 3.2?

Comment: thanks for your response.  Seems the bug still exists.  Following is my python version got from the Python Shell (IDLE): Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 20 2011, 21:29:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Comment: @KurtisZhao: You're running 3.2 released in Feb 2011. 3.2.1, with the bug fix, was released in Jul 2011. Most systems should be running 3.2.3 by now, released Apr 2012. 3.3.0 was released in Sep 2012 and has a lot of improvements, including shebang support on Windows, built-in virtual environments, redesigned OS/IO exception handling, 120x speedup for the decimal module, and memory saving with the new flexible string and dict key sharing implementations.

Comment: You are right that it is a bug on 3.2.  I re-installed 3.3 on my win7 machine and it works now.  Thank you for your comments.